# Firebase completion block not working as expected

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm working on an iOS app with Firebase and I'm finding the completion handlers to be very unreliable.

Based on the code example in their documentation, I have the following:

```
...
let ref = Firebase(url:self.FIREBASE_URL)
let userRef = ref.childByAppendingPath("user").childByAppendingPath(userID)
userRef.updateChildValues(prefData, withCompletionBlock: { (error:NSError?, ref:Firebase!) in
    if(error != nil){
        self.showErrorWithTitle("Database Error", description: error!.localizedDescription)
        print("error in updateUserPrefs \(error!.localizedDescription)")
    }
})
```

This code works most of the time but there are two big issues,

1) If I want to use persistence:

```
Firebase.defaultConfig().persistenceEnabled = true
```

The completion block never fires.

2) If the app is offline, the completion block never fires.

The simple scenario I am trying to develop:

- User changes info
- User taps save
- Show activity indicator
- On completion, remove activity indicator and close save window

Thank you for your time

Comment: Did the value get saved on the server?

Comment: No, just locally. I have a follow-up question in another post. They are similar, but different enough to set as a different post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35989095/firebase-disk-persistence

Comment: The completion listener only fires when the data has been written to the server. So I'm not sure what you're looking for in this question.

Comment: Are you using a physical device or the simulator?

Comment: I'm using both the simulator and a physical device

Comment: @Frank. I would expect an error to be returned in the completion block if it cannot be written at all. Or I would expect no error, but the completion returned because the data is saved locally (to be synced later). I find it odd that the completion is completely silent. That is different than any other API I have used in the past.

Comment: The change is applied to the local cache immediately, you don't need a completion listener for that. The completion listener will fire when the data has been written to the server.

Comment: @ Frank, Thank you for time/help here. To your last point, when does the data sync with the server. It never seems to happen. Can you force a sync? I cannot find documentation to make that happen. Also, it would be helpful for the completion handler to update UI once the save is complete (even if it is local data, there can be race conditions where the view is presented before the data is cached).  I've seen this with CoreData in the past

Comment: @BuyinBrian I think what Frank is trying to say is that the local cache is updated synchronously, so you don't need the completion block to be notified of that.